# Redirect too many times htacces switching to https

Tags: redirect, htaccess

When I change the redirect https in my .htaccess the site returns the message "Too many redirects" loop.

This is the modified .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.it/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also added in the wp-config.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding redirect to htaccess in the way that you have done will not work without adjudicating the site url to be https as well. If it is http, you will get endless redirect due to wordpress detecting that you are trying to access a non canonical URL (the https), and will try to redirect you to the canonical one, which is based on the site url, which is http, and then the htacess will redirect to https again only for wordpress to redirect to http, and so on.

Comment: Check the URLs specified in the wp-options table. Should include https, not http. That's what Mark is indicating.

Answer (score 0):

Since many shared hosts use additional DNS management now such as such as Cloudflare...or similar, do you know if you are using such thing ?

If so you need to make sure cloudflare is set to Full https as well as possibly using a cloudflare plugin to prevent too many redirects or loops.

Answer (score -1):

do you want to push all the traffic to https?

i have ssl installed on my site, and i use this code to force all the incoming traffic to HHTPS : (put it above all of your codes in .htaccess )

**first remove the previous code you added to wp-config.php**
**and remove the previous code in .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.it/$1 [R,L]
```

be sure to know your server port. and replace it if it's not 80.

here is more info if you need : - i took my code from here :)

i hope it help you too

[use https with .htaccess](http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/website/ssl/force-website-to-use-ssl)

Comment: yes, the site is on a shared hosting which provides the SSL activation but since the coexistence also the version of the website http must force the redirect via https. I tried your solution but it does not work.

Comment: @user1269141
my site is on a shared host too.
1 - did you go to the link i posted at the end of my answer?
2 - go to Dashboard> setting > General> change your site address and put **https://** at the first of your site address and hit save.
3 - after this , please first clear the browser cache - and 
type your site address without https, to see if the redirection works or not?